# Ctrl+Y keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When using my Windows 7 PC, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> keyboard shortcut does nothing. Interesting notes:

- Choosing the same command from the menu works (such as Edit > Redo)
- Both the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> keys work fine independently of each other
- Any additional combination of keys works fine (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, etc)
- For programs where Ctrl+Y is not the shortcut for Redo (in Adobe Illustrator, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> switches to Outline view), the shortcut still does not work.

So, it seems that something is globally preventing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> combination (and ONLY that combination) from working properly.

I'm using a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000 keyboard with Intellitype Pro installed, and Windows 7 64-bit. I also have a Logitech Performance MX mouse with their Control Center software installed, but I've disabled it for testing.

Here are the troubleshooting steps I've tried (with no effect):

- Using another keyboard
- Booting into safe mode
- Connecting to the PC via Remote Desktop
- Disabling all non-essential services
- Upgrading Intellitype Pro to the latest version (Mouse and Keyboard Center)

Can anyone think of what may be causing this, or of any utilities that might help me track down what is suppressing this shortcut?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling intellitype and then trying CTRL+Y? Have you done a virus\malware scan on your system?

Comment: Do you have anything installed/running which might be globally intercepting keystrokes? eg. AutoHotKey? Can you define CTRL+Y as a shortcut in another application that allows you to define your own shortcuts by automatically reading the pressed the key combination (can't think of any right now, sorry)?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? For me, ctrl+y and ctrl+e are the only two letters that don't work.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, due to a Zen Coding plugin in Notepad++ that uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for something else. Given that Notepad++ is always opened on my computer, it blocked the keyboard shortcut everywhere.

Removing the plugin resolved the issue.

Comment: You can also uncomment this line: `addMenuItem('Evaluate Math Expression', 'evaluate_math_expression', 'Ctrl+Y');`. For me the file was in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\NppScripting\includes\Zen Coding.js`

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was closing Notepad++ `:(`

Seems that there is a plugin that uses the `ctrl+y` hotkey and is intercepting globally.

Comment: Hey anon - I don't believe Notepad++ was the culprit for me, as I made sure to close all my programs when troubleshooting this. I am a Notepad++ user, so it's entirely possible, however. My fix was to reinstall Windows, and this hasn't happened since. Thanks!