# Notepad++ Ctrl+Y shortcut active in other applications, even after reassigning new combination

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Whenever I've got my **Notepad++** running in the background, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> combination doesn't work in other applications (e.g. Illustrator or IrfanView). By default it is assigned to a redo function of the Scintilla 'module' (Menu Settings / Shortcut mapper / Scintilla commands), but even after I reassign a different combination to that function, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> shortcut doesn't work elsewhere. It seems that no other Notepad++ function nor plugin has this shortcut assigned. Everything goes normal after I shut down the editor. Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

My system: Windows 7.

Comment: @jww - The question is acceptable here because NotePad++ is often used for programming. Marking this as looking Okay, but the author should consider taking it elsewhere.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. What's the best way to move it? Simply cut and paste?

Comment: I've just flagged it and asked a moderator to move it.

Comment: See also [here](http://superuser.com/questions/508915/ctrly-keyboard-shortcut-not-working).